# Getting a black screen the first time I try to play a video on Android, using StageVideo

Tags: android, video, air, stagevideo

The first time I play the video, I get a black screen, sound works though.

This happens when using StageVideo, latest Air version on an Android tablet (Samsung Tab S 10.5 T800, capable enough of this task).

However, after I click stop and then play again, the video now does work.

Any ideas what could be happening here?, same code works perfectly on an iPad 2, which has way lower specs.

Answer (score 0):

The stage video is switching a render state. It's an annoying bug, and this is what you can do as a patch.

1 Try to play.

2 if RENDER_STATE has changed to UNAVAILABLE or SOFTWARE, play again!

This will cause black flickering and not the best UX, but the clip will play after a second or 2.

```
_stageVideo.addEventListener(StageVideoEvent.RENDER_STATE, function (e:StageVideoEvent):void{
            trace ("RENDER STATE: ", e.status);
            if (e.status == VideoStatus.UNAVAILABLE || e.status == VideoStatus.SOFTWARE)
            {
                _ns.play(_videoURL);
            }
        });
```

Please share if you find a better solution. Thank you.